# C++ programmin with singleton

Tags: visual-c++, optimization, static, singleton

i have list of diff. classes.

in that man static variables is there.

i need to remove the static variables .. and singleton class instead of static variables.

How can i achieve this . any suggestions?

Comment: please provide us from some of your current code! thanks in advance

Comment: code is like .. it have 10 file corresponding header files to them . i want to remove all static variables from classes .. n need to use singleton or any other solutions ..  any class static variable used anywhere.